# How to italicise lettrine font

Tags: italic, lettrine

I am using the lettrine package but would like it to be italicised. Is there a way to italicise all of the text in the lettrine command? When I use

`\textit{lettrine{T}{his}}`

the 'T' is italicised but the 'his' is not.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Since `\lettrine` sets the second argument in small caps, the likely reason that "his" isn't set in italic is that the font doesn't have italic small caps.  (Many fonts don't.}

Comment: You could also pick a font that does have slanted small caps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\renewcommand{\LettrineFontHook}{\itshape}% for the initial
\renewcommand{\LettrineTextFont}{\itshape}% for the second argument
\begin{document}
\lettrine{L}{orem} ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut
enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi
ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in
culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: That looks great! I want to be able to use both italicised and non-italicised in the same document. Is there a way of creating a command that doesn't overwrite the lettrine command?

Comment: You can put `\renewcommand{\LettrineFontHook}{\upshape}` and `\renewcommand{\LettrineTextFont}{\scshape}` in the document when you want to revert to the usual look.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately the second argument ends up being the same font as the rest of the text instead of being capitalised. Is there a way of ensuring the second argument is both capitalised and italicised?

Comment: If the font has italic small caps, then `\renewcommand{\LettrineTextFont}{\scshape\itshape}` will do what you want.

Comment: thank you for the suggestions!