# How to Italicize (One Time) a Lettrine *(Question Updated)*

Tags: horizontal-alignment, italic, lettrine, italic-correction

**This question has been revised. Please see below.**

I would like to be able to occasionally italicize a lettrine.

I am aware of the good answer given in [How to italicise lettrine font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/585247/how-to-italicise-lettrine-font), but unfortunately for me, it provides a global solution.

I am presently working on a document with many lettrines and would like to italicize only one of them. It would cause me a greater problem if *all* similar lettrines were italicized.

Please consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsthm,latexsym,amssymb,amsmath,verbatim}

\hoffset 10pt \voffset -45pt
\oddsidemargin 12pt \evensidemargin 10pt \topmargin 35pt
\headheight 25pt \textheight 8in \textwidth 6in
\headsep 55pt \marginparwidth 35pt

\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{verse,anyfontsize}



%% SUBROUTINE TO BE ABLE TO USE BOTH VERSE AND LETTRINES
%% And needed for this MWE so that the lettrine is reasonably large and rises above the adjoined statement. 
\def\startverse#1#2{%
  \begin{minipage}{4in}%
  \firstline#1\relax%
  \def\verselineB{#2}%
  \if Q\versalletter\def\descstrut{\strut}\else\def\descstrut{}\fi%
  \def\Versal{\textcolor{RoyalRed}{%
             \scalerel*{$\fontsize{28}{30}\selectfont\versalletter$}%
                       {\def\stacktype{L}\stackon{T\descstrut}{T}}}}%
  \setbox0=\hbox{\Versal\,}%
%  \def\leftoffset{-15pt}%WHAT OP ASKED FOR, BUT NOT BEST, IMHO
  \def\leftoffset{-.3\wd0}%
  \hspace*{\wd0}\hspace{\leftoffset}%
    \verselineA\\%
  \hspace*{\wd0}\hspace{\leftoffset}%
    \llap{\smash{\box0}}%
    \verselineB\strut%
  \end{minipage}%
}

\def\firstline#1#2\relax{\def\versalletter{#1}\def\verselineA{#2}}


% % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % %
% % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % %


\begin{document}
\Large

\lettrine[lines=2,lhang=.0,loversize=0.35,findent=0pt]{\color{red}{\textbf{L}}}{\textbf{\color{red}\textit{ettrine to be italicized}}} \\

\textit{\lettrine[lines=2,lhang=.0,loversize=0.35,findent=0pt]{\color{red}{\textbf{L}}}{\textbf{\color{red}\textit{ettrine italicized}}} } \\

\vskip 15pt

And when I try to push the statement to the right with either an $hskip$, $hspace$, or $hspace*$, nothing happens---although any of these would work in unitalicized case.

\hskip 25pt \hspace{25pt} \hspace*{25pt} \textit{\lettrine[lines=2,lhang=.0,loversize=0.35,findent=0pt]{\color{red}{\textbf{L}}}{\textbf{\color{red}\textit{ettrine italicized}}} }
\end{document}
```

And the output

[image]

Although I am able to italicize the lettrine, for some reason unbeknownst to me it shifts the statement containing the italicized lettrine far to left and I cannot force it back with either an `\hskip`, `\hspace`, or `\hspace*` command.

(Original) QUESTION: (i) is there a better way to italicize a lettrine (along with the rest of the content ordinarily appearing in smallcaps?) on a one-time basis (ii) What is causing the italicized lettrine above to be positioned all the way to the left? (iii) Lacking a better approach, how may I now force it back to the position of an unitalicized lettrine?

**UPDATED INFORMATION** Since posting the original question, I noticed that I neglected to add any additional sentences to accompany my italicized lettrine. Since doing so, I have discovered that the said lettrine fails to left justify the text after the prescribed number of skips. Ordinarily, I think it best to delete the question and post a new one. However, an answer (correct for the original question posed) has been offered---so I cannot delete this one. I apologize for the confusion, but the alternative is to post some revised code and output, and rephrase the question. Please see UPDATED QUESTION.

**REVISED MWE**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsthm,latexsym,amssymb,amsmath,verbatim}

\hoffset 10pt \voffset -45pt
\oddsidemargin 12pt \evensidemargin 10pt \topmargin 35pt
\headheight 25pt \textheight 8in \textwidth 6in
\headsep 55pt \marginparwidth 35pt

\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{verse,anyfontsize}




%% SUBROUTINE TO BE ABLE TO USE BOTH VERSE AND LETTRINES
%% And needed for this MWE so that the lettrine is reasonably large and rises above the adjoined statement. 
\def\startverse#1#2{%
  \begin{minipage}{4in}%
  \firstline#1\relax%
  \def\verselineB{#2}%
  \if Q\versalletter\def\descstrut{\strut}\else\def\descstrut{}\fi%
  \def\Versal{\textcolor{RoyalRed}{%
             \scalerel*{$\fontsize{28}{30}\selectfont\versalletter$}%
                       {\def\stacktype{L}\stackon{T\descstrut}{T}}}}%
  \setbox0=\hbox{\Versal\,}%
%  \def\leftoffset{-15pt}%WHAT OP ASKED FOR, BUT NOT BEST, IMHO
  \def\leftoffset{-.3\wd0}%
  \hspace*{\wd0}\hspace{\leftoffset}%
    \verselineA\\%
  \hspace*{\wd0}\hspace{\leftoffset}%
    \llap{\smash{\box0}}%
    \verselineB\strut%
  \end{minipage}%
}

\def\firstline#1#2\relax{\def\versalletter{#1}\def\verselineA{#2}}


% % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % %
% % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % %



    \begin{document}
    \Large
    
    \lettrine[lines=2,lhang=.0,loversize=0.35,findent=0pt]{\color{red}{\textbf{L}}}{\textbf{\color{red}\textit{ettrine to be italicized}}} A sentence to go along with the lettrine. A sentence to go along with the lettrine. A sentence to go along with the lettrine.\\
    
    \textit{\lettrine[lines=2,lhang=.0,loversize=0.35,findent=0pt]{\color{red}{\textbf{L}}}{\textbf{\color{red}\textit{ettrine italicized}}}} A sentence to go along with the lettrine. A sentence to go along with the lettrine. A sentence to go along with the lettrine. A sentence to go along with the lettrine. A sentence to go along with the lettrine. \\
    
    \vskip 15pt
    
    As you can see, the text is not left-justtified after two lineskips; And, when I try to push the statement to the right with either an $hskip$, $hspace$, or $hspace*$, nothing happens.
    
    
    
    \textit{\lettrine[lines=2,lhang=.0,loversize=0.35,findent=0pt]{\color{red}{\textbf{L}}}{\textbf{\color{red}\textit{ettrine italicized}}}} A sentence to go along with the lettrine. A sentence to go along with the lettrine. A sentence to go along with the lettrine. A sentence to go along with the lettrine. A sentence to go along with the lettrine.
    \end{document}
```

**REVISED OUTPUT**

[image]

**REVISED QUESTION: How may I italicize a lettrine (one time) so that the aforesaid undesirable happenings do not occur?**

Thank you.

Comment: Put the `\textit` *inside* the lettrine arguments, as in `\lettrine[lines=2,lhang=.0,loversize=0.35,findent=0pt]{\textit{\color{red}{\textbf{L}}}}{\textbf{\color{red}\textit{ettrine italicized}}}`

Comment: I was going to say the same as @StevenB.Segletes `\textit{\lettrine` can't work, specify italic at the same points you are specifying red and bold. (also you shouldn't change the  question so much after an answer posted)

Comment: I updated my answer

Comment: Just added the new content to my former answer without changing the code.

Comment: @Simon Dispa Thank you kindly for the update and I apologize for the confusion. Kind regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I commented, don't wrap `\lettrine` inside the `\textit`...do it the opposite...place the `\textit` inside the lettrine arguments.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsthm,latexsym,amssymb,amsmath,verbatim}

\hoffset 10pt \voffset -45pt
\oddsidemargin 12pt \evensidemargin 10pt \topmargin 35pt
\headheight 25pt \textheight 8in \textwidth 6in
\headsep 55pt \marginparwidth 35pt

\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{verse,anyfontsize}



%% SUBROUTINE TO BE ABLE TO USE BOTH VERSE AND LETTRINES
%% And needed for this MWE so that the lettrine is reasonably large and rises above the adjoined statement. 
\def\startverse#1#2{%
  \begin{minipage}{4in}%
  \firstline#1\relax%
  \def\verselineB{#2}%
  \if Q\versalletter\def\descstrut{\strut}\else\def\descstrut{}\fi%
  \def\Versal{\textcolor{RoyalRed}{%
             \scalerel*{$\fontsize{28}{30}\selectfont\versalletter$}%
                       {\def\stacktype{L}\stackon{T\descstrut}{T}}}}%
  \setbox0=\hbox{\Versal\,}%
%  \def\leftoffset{-15pt}%WHAT OP ASKED FOR, BUT NOT BEST, IMHO
  \def\leftoffset{-.3\wd0}%
  \hspace*{\wd0}\hspace{\leftoffset}%
    \verselineA\\%
  \hspace*{\wd0}\hspace{\leftoffset}%
    \llap{\smash{\box0}}%
    \verselineB\strut%
  \end{minipage}%
}

\def\firstline#1#2\relax{\def\versalletter{#1}\def\verselineA{#2}}


% % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % %
% % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % %


\begin{document}
\Large

\lettrine[lines=2,lhang=.0,loversize=0.35,findent=0pt]{\color{red}{\textbf{L}}}{\textbf{\color{red}\textit{ettrine to be italicized}}} \\

\lettrine[lines=2,lhang=.0,loversize=0.35,findent=0pt]{\textit{\color{red}{\textbf{L}}}}{\textbf{\color{red}\textit{ettrine italicized}}}  \\

\vskip 15pt

And when I try to push the statement to the right with either an $hskip$, $hspace$, or $hspace*$, nothing happens---although any of these would work in unitalicized case.

\hskip 25pt \hspace{25pt} \hspace*{25pt} \lettrine[lines=2,lhang=.0,loversize=0.35,findent=0pt]{\textit{\color{red}{\textbf{L}}}}{\textbf{\color{red}\textit{ettrine italicized}}} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this very fine answer. It nicely takes care of all the problems in one "fell swoop". I apologize for being able to respond to your comment when it came in, but I was called away. I didn't have a chance to check it out until several minutes ago. Thanks again and for posting this answer!

Answer (score 2):

[image: y]

Try (a simpler line)

```
\lettrine[lines=2,lhang=.0,loversize=0.35,findent=0pt]{\bfseries\color{red}\itshape L}{\bfseries\color{red}\itshape ettrine italicized shifted}
```

You might need to use `findent=2pt` to take care of an italic `T`.

With

```
\newcommand{\ilettrine}[2]{%
\lettrine[lines=2,lhang=.0,loversize=0.35,findent=0pt]{\color{blue}\bfseries\itshape#1}{\color{blue}\bfseries\itshape#2}    
}
```

and using  `\ilettrine{L}{orem ipsum dolor sit amet}`

[image: z]

**UPDATE** (Using the same code with the longer texts)

[image: zz]

```
% % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % %
% % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % %

\newcommand{\ilettrine}[2]{%
    \lettrine[lines=2,lhang=.0,loversize=0.35,findent=0pt]{\bfseries\color{red}\itshape#1}{\bfseries\color{red}\itshape#2}  
}
\begin{document}
    \Large
    
    \ilettrine{L}{ettrine to be italicized}A sentence to go along with the lettrine. A sentence to go along with the lettrine. A sentence to go along with the lettrine.\\
    
    \ilettrine{L}{ettrine to be italicized}A sentence to go along with the lettrine. A sentence to go along with the lettrine. A sentence to go along with the lettrine. A sentence to go along with the lettrine. A sentence to go along with the lettrine. \\
    

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, I have been able to reproduce your output. It appears that the first `hspace*` moves the lettrine and the second `hspace*` shifts the rest. Thank you. In regards to (ii) and (iii), do you know what initially caused the problem? Was it because of the way I italicized the lettrine? Do you know of a better way to italicize lettrines on an individual basis instead of the way I did? Thank you again.

Comment: I just noticed you updated your answer about the time I posted the last comment. I look forward to checking it out.

Comment: @mlchristians I am looking into the issue. Thank you for your feedback (I made another update, the last for today)

Comment: I have updated the question, as I discovered that when sentences are added after the italicized lettrine, they do not left-justify after the prescribed number of skips. In my update, I have noted that your answer appears to be correct for the question as it was originally posed. Thank you.